# Access FileBag file array in a foreach loop

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I've been trying to access this filebag from the request and I've had no luck:

This is what I'm sending:

[image]

This is what I recieve when doing **dd($request)**:

[image]

yet when trying to output or access it:

for example:

```
dd($request->file('files')[0]);
```

it outputs

```
message: "Cannot use object of type Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag as array",
```

I have tried aswell

```
dd($request->file('files'));
```

but it outputs **NULL**

and I have tried too:

```
$t = $request->files->all();
dd($t);
```

this one outputs: []

The way I'm sending it is using axios

```
let formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('draft', true);
                formData.append('global_id', this.paragraph.ManualBook_SectionParagraphGlobalID);
                formData.append('newparagraph', this.newParagraph.tobeCreated);
                formData.append('paragraph_id', this.paragraph.ManualBook_SectionParagraphGlobalID);
                formData.append('display_order', this.paragraph.DisplayOrder);
                formData.append('section_id', this.current_section);
                formData.append('RCBulletinNumber', this.paragraph.RCBulletinNumber);
                formData.append('paragraph_title', this.paragraph.ParagraphTitle);
                formData.append('paragraph_text', this.paragraph.ParagraphText);
                formData.append('go_live_date', this.getGoodDate(this.edited_paragraph.go_live_date));
                formData.append('revision', this.edited_paragraph.revision);
                formData.append('revision_number', this.paragraph.RevisionVersion);
                formData.append('files', this.files);

                axios.post(window.baseURL + 'api/admin/paragraph_editor', {
                    formData
                }, {
                        headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                        }
                    }....
```

Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to upload multiple files with `FormData` API via an AJAX request, then you need to append each and every file to a `FormData` object. Assuming your input file field as the below:

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple>
```

Assuming `this.files` will be containing multiple files. So we will loop over the files to append them to the `FormData` object as the below:

```
let formData = new FormData();

Array.from(this.files).forEach(function(file){
    formData.append('files[]', file);
});
```

And now you can grab those files in your controller's method as the below:

```
$request->file('files');
```

Hope this would help you!